# Different compiling version while trying to run an electron project

Tags: node.js, electron, node-gyp

I currently an trying to make a node js project using electron and node-gyp for c addons. But when I try to run my program using

`electron index.js`

I get this error:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: The module '/home/ubspy/Code/Node-c-test/build/Release/addons.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 54. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or`npm install`).
at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen]
```

I've tried reinstalling all the packages, and recompiling all the source code, I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after many a trial and error, after upgrading electron to the most recent beta version the module versions matched, and the program ran flawlessly.